# Does Mathematica use first order or second order order unification?

Tags: pattern-matching

When Mathematica is pattern-matching expressions, does it use first order or second order [unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))?

Just to clarify the difference between first order and second order unification:
In second order unification, it is possible to replace a pattern variable with a function:
 When the expression `3+3` or `Plus[3,3]` is matched with the pattern `f[3]`, the matching succeeds and `f` is bound to `Plus[#, #]&` or `Plus[3, #]&`.

Comment: Does first order unification include the constrain (** /; **) operator?

Comment: Just to clarify the difference between first order and second order unification.

Comment: In Second order unification, it is possible to replace a pattern variable with a function:

Answer (score 12):

I am not an expert in the field, but ...

According to [Roman Maeder](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v4i1/columns/maeder/53-63_Roman41.mj.pdf) (and he **is** an expert):

> The process of unification should be easy to understand for
>   Mathematica users, since a weaker form of it —pattern matching— is the
>   fundamental operating principle of Mathematica’s evaluator.

So, no unification is done in native Mma.

If you need it, Maeder presents in that 2 articles series a package with a modified evaluator that aims to bring second order unification to Mma.

Just for those to whom *unification* means only a physics Grail, should Mma have  unification you could do things like:

```
f[x_,a] /. f[b,y_]-> {x,y}
(*
-> {b,a}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain the difference between unification and matching for I think the difference isn't clear in my head.

Comment: @user1176201 I prefer not, because subtle things may be wrong in my explanation (as I said, I am not an expert). I suggest: 1) Read Maeder's articles linked above 2) post a question in cs.SE

Comment: @11Kilobytes In my opinion, the two should operate as follows: (matching) `Match[a, b] == c` iff `b /. c == a` (e.g. `Match[{1,1}, {x_, x_}] == {Verbatim@x_ -> 1}`). (unification) `Unify[a, b] == c` iff, for all `x`, `MatchQ[x, a] && MatchQ[x, b]` iff `MatchQ[x, c]`. (e.g. `Unify[f[x_,a], f[b,y_]] == f[b,a]`). Or you might want `Unify` to output a list of rules/dictionary that translates both `a` and `b` into the unified pattern `c`.